# Cracked & Chipping Porch

Tags: concrete

I have a 25 x 7 ft porch that has some weird 1/4 inch layer of chalky skim coat on top of old concrete from the previous owner. One half of the porch has a pretty damaged area. I tried patching the bad areas with RapidSet Cement All but I did a poor job making it smooth and its still chipping and cracking in some parts. The porch is painted as well.

what would be the fix here? Do I need to remove the chalky skim coat or is there a less invasive way to fix this? Any advice would be appreciated. Pictures of the affected half are attached.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Remove the paint before trying to repair.

Cement repair must be on clean, unpainted, not loose, cement.

Cement repair will not stick to paint, loose stuff, chalky stuff, it is just a waste of money and labour.

Preparation sulks, but is the most important part of a good job, also why I have not painted in too many years.

Comment: "Preparation sulks" is a funny, yet highly appropriate autocowrecks! I was going to fix it, but it's actually better this way. :)

Comment: @FreeMan   That is a better excuse and I will go with it.  Better than the true brain freeze.

Comment: mmmm.... ice cream for breakfast! :D

Comment: On a more useful note: Preparation is _always_ the most important, time consuming, and least popular part of _any_ paint job. If you don't do the prep right, there's little point in applying the paint. Unless, of course, you have time & money to burn.

Answer (score 0):

Use or get Power sprayer.

Power wash the whole surface with it (more cracks could be coming in the future.

Get concrete primer (liquid in a bottle) and apply to the surface.

Now you have two choice:

Redo the whole surface with Self leveling concrete "recap"

or just fix the cracked parts.

Example

at ACE Hardware
[image: Source ACE hardware]